# How do I Put an External Drive into My Xbox 360 Slim?

Tags: xbox-360, hard-drive

How can I put a Microsoft Xbox 360 external hard drive into my Xbox 360 slim without messing up anything else on my Xbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are if you have an Xbox 360 slim, your Xbox doesn't have much storage space on it. Maybe just enough for a few profiles and a few games. This storage space can be increased SAFELY for under $50. Many people claim you can take that wire and this one and plug it into a PC hard drive and have a 50% of not having an explosion happen, but this is the only way someone can add a hard drive safely because it is supported by microsoft! Here are the instructions:

1. Get a Microsoft Licensed Xbox hard drive from any Game Stop or online. They range from $35 (120 GB) to $100+ (450GB+). Here is a 120 GB one: [Rakutan](http://www.rakuten.com/prod/portable-120gb-hdd-hard-drive-disk-for-xbox-360-slim/248310212.html?listingId=282336199&sclid=pla_google_imagestore&adid=29963&gclid=CjwKEAjwluetBRD98L639p35p0QSJACC8BlKqBkmucNYuoGNqxmnl2HYrGy4Axq_Av5mmGklLX5g3hoCMujw_wcB)
2. Prepare your Xbox. UNPLUG EVERYTHING!!! Take your Xbox and look for a button that will release a cover on the back of the Xbox. This will be the drive area. Here is a pic of where it may be:

[image]

or

[image]

In the above picture, the button is disguised as a vent, but you actually pull it towards you to open.

3. Take any plastic off the drive that may have come with it and insert it in the proper orientation. This is easy to tell as it is uniquely shaped. Make sure the ribbon that states the storage size is facing outward. Here is how it looks:

[image]

or

[image]

4. Replace the cover and plug everything back in. Power on the Xbox. If it all went well, it should power on fine. To make sure your Xbox recognizes the hard drive, press the home button on your controller and choose settings > system settings. Click on Storage or Memory and see if something named 'Hard Drive' appears in the list. If it does, congrats, you now have an external drive connected to your Xbox.

Why is having a drive so important?: Some games require you to have an external drive to play. Here is where it tells you on the game case:

[image]

Hope I could help somebody!

-Nick